# What is the pythonic way to convert day and month in string format to date in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have day and month in string format **23rd Sep**, I would like to convert the above string to the current date **23/09/2021**. I achieved that using the below code, what is the more pythonic way to do this.?

```
from datetime import datetime

# datetime object containing current date and time
now = datetime.now()
year = str(now).split('-')
year =year[0]
dm = '23rd Sep'
s = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', dm)
day_month = " ".join(s[::len(s)-1] )
date = day_month +' ' + year
dmap = {'Jan':'January','Feb':'Febuary','Mar':'March','Sep':'September'}
import arrow
for i in dmap.keys():
    s = date.split(' ')
    if i in s:
        s[1] = dmap[i]
        clean_date = ' '.join(s)
        p = arrow.get(clean_date, 'DD MMMM YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
print(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

s = '23rd Sep'
pd.Timestamp(s + ' 2021')
Out[1]: Timestamp('2021-09-23 00:00:00')
```

If you want it in DMY format:

```
_.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
Out[2]: '23/09/2021'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#) to get current date and extract year from it. (No need to hardcode year)

Then, use it again for date conversion.  Followed by `strftime()` for formatting date string.

```
import pandas as pd

year = pd.to_datetime('now').year     # Get current year
dm = '23rd Sep'

pd.to_datetime(dm + ' ' + str(year)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Output:

```
'23/09/2021'
```